# Similar coefficients in a GAM factor-smooth interaction

Tags: time-series, generalized-additive-model

I estimated two generalized additive models. Both contain a time-trend across 315 waves of measurement and a dummy group factor ("comparison group" vs. "target group"). I used both available approaches in a model containing both a s(x) (x= time) and a s(wday) (weekday) season factor:

1. In the the first model, I used the group dummy as a simple factor, which leads to the estimation of separate smooths for both groups and both predictors--that is one season effect and one trend for the comparison group and one season and trend for the target group.
2. To gain information about statistical differences between the groups, I changed the group factor into an ordered factor. This should lead to the estimation of reference smooths for the weekday and time trend, and difference smooths for the target group. The code is this. As the dependent variables were proportions (in our case, the proportion of tweets with a certain content to the overall number of tweets of the groups), I used the beta-distribution. I also tried different ones, but this version resulted in the cleanest residual and the only gam.check result with non-sign. values.

```
#Separate smooths model
#<==============================================================>

gamm_sep_trends <- gam(value ~ group + 
                         s(wday, by=group, bs="tp", k=7)+
                         s(x, by=group, bs="cr", k=305), 
                    method="ML", 
                    family=betar(link="logit"), 
                    data=corona_tweets_both_long)
summary(gamm_sep_trends)



#Difference smooth model
#<==============================================================>
gamm_interaction <- gam(value ~ group.ord + 
                         s(wday, bs="tp", k=7)+
                         s(wday, by=group.ord, bs="tp", k=7)+
                         s(x, bs="cr", k=305)+
                         s(x, by=group.ord, bs="cr", k=305), 
                       method="ML", 
                       family=betar(link="logit"), 
                       data=corona_tweets_both_long)
summary(gamm_interaction)
```

The problem is that the coefficients in both models are rather similar. For instance the "separate-smooth model" results in a time trend smooth of 18 for the comparison group and 34 for the target group. When estimating the "difference smooth model", I would expect the difference smooth to be 34-18 = 16. However, it is 33....

Can anybody tell what could be the problem? Or is my expectation wrong?

I am happy for some hints.

All the best,
--Holger

Comment: When you say coefficients do you mean EDFs? Also note that the reference smooth isn't orthogonal to the group-specific smooths. I doubt you need `k = 305` in either case; you're just making fitting super slow (or slower than it needs to be).

Comment: Dear Gavin, thank you very much for the comment. Yes I meant the EDF. In the "separate smooth model", the EDFs are 17 (control group) and 34 (target group) and in the "difference smooth model" they are 18 and 33. What do you mean with "the reference smooth isn't orthogonal to the group-specific smooths"? Sorry, for the stupid question.

Comment: It seemed that you assumed you could add up the EDFs and they should match the one with the factor by. I've noticed that you can get very different fits when using ordered vs unordered factors and with the ordered on, your fits overall can vary depending on what the reference level is. I think what's happening is that you can estimate a wiggly difference smooth if there are lots of differences between a reference smooth and the target group smooth. Hence you need to set some expectation on the wiggliness of the differences by keeping `k` lower

Comment: Hi Gavin, thanks again. I reduced k to the point where gam.check reported problems and the EDFs did only slightly change. In the paper I will report the two base smooths as well as noting the significance of the difference. I guess there is nothing wrong then....Actually I indeed thought that the difference smooth for the comparison group is simply the difference between both base smooths.

Comment: Hi Holger; it is the smooth difference btw the reference smooth and "smooth" for the target group, but only in the sense that it is parameterised to model a smooth difference to the reference smooth. The fit is now $f_{\text{ref}}(x) + f_{\text{diff}_{g}}(x)$ but notice that imposing a constraint of smoothness on the difference is a different thing to imposing a smooth constraint on an actual function fitted to that groups data (i.e. in the non-ordered case). While conceptually the ordered behaviour is as per the default constrasts in a linear model, in practice the smoothing complicates it.